# When to use Media Streaming Engine and WebEx meeting and can they compliment each other

Tags: video-streaming, wowza, opentok, tokbox, webex

I am kind of newbie in the field of Live Media content streaming. I am searching for RTMP compatible Streaming media solutions and there are many ..Wowza is one and then there is tokbox.

So my question is, if I want to stream a live content I can use RTMP server or I can also use WebEx type of meeting management software. 
Why will someone write a server side code to use RTMP compatible streaming engine ? When is it useful? Why not just use WebEx instead of hassle to stream your content using the Wowza or tokbox ?

Need an expert opinion regarding what are the usage scenario for using a Streaming media engine vs just simply using the WebEx type meeting for your live streaming need. 
What are the advantage and disadvantage of using each option?

Comment: I want to give you some scenario here for comparing the cost. Webex is  $39/month for hosting meeting with 25 people. Where as RTMP server cost $55+/month + 0.005/10KB of streaming.  So looks like using the RTMP sever is a better option cost wise. But not sure what are other benefits or disadvantages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine if you want to build a healthcare app where a patient can open the app and call a doctor from the app. The doctor (at his computer) can pick up the call and video chat with his patient from your website. If you have your own RTMP server, you can build a scenario like this. Since your app controls everything, you can also set up payment within your app and bill your patient by the minute.

Now lets see how you might accomplish the some thing with WebEx. The patient would have to email the doctor, set up an appointment time, get a webex account, make sure the doctor also applies for a webex account, give the doctor your WebEx username, meet at the specified time on webex.

One is used for consumers, and the other is used for building a business.

Comment: Great insight ! Yes, I now understand the value proposition here.